# Messed up JSON return

Tags: python, json

I have a return from a JSON call via curl that returns this:

```
{
    'result': {
        'today_runtime': 830,
        'month_runtime': 39991,
        'today_energy': 1293,
        'month_energy': 55326,
        'local_time': '2022-11-27 13:50:54',
        'electricity_charge': \[0, 0, 0\],
        'current_power': 93860
    },
    'error_code': 0
}
```

I need values from the key value pairs in the inner bracketed section, and I know how to extract them without the:

```
{'result':
```

and

```
, 'error_code': 0}
```

as I have manually chopped them off and get the expected result when extracting values.

Comment: That's not JSON at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
{
    'result': {
        'today_runtime': 830,
        'month_runtime': 39991,
        'today_energy': 1293,
        'month_energy': 55326,
        'local_time': '2022-11-27 13:50:54',
        'electricity_charge': \[0, 0, 0\],
        'current_power': 93860
    },
    'error_code': 0
}
```

That is a dictionary.  It has two keys: "result" and "error_code".

The value of the "result" key is also a dictionary, with seven keys.

(The "electricity_charge" key is odd, though.  Why are the backslashes `\[` and `\]` there?  I assume that's a formatting quirk of yours.)

Presuming you assigned this dictionary to a variable named `data`, you would access the information like this:

```
data['result']['today_runtime']
data['result']['month_runtime']
...
data['result']['current_power']
data['error_code']
```

This is all very straightforward dictionary syntax.  It is not "nonsense" at all.

Comment: Cheers, that does work, didnt make any sense to me and the one thing i didnt try because it just didnt make sense to me, all the articles i read kept asserting to use numerical indexes etc:)

And yes those backslashes were an aberration of pasting into here...

Thanks again

Comment: @AdrianM Numeric indexes are for lists, not dictionaries.

Comment: Clearly still learning, probably not my favourite first experience of a language :)